# Does twilio support two way SMS service

Tags: sms, twilio, sms-gateway

I want to know that either twilio support two way SMS service i.e it is bidirectional or not. If yes, please let me know how can I implement it for two way sms service.

In case if it not supported let me know about some other SMS gateway that support this functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Twilio employee here.

Short answer is: **yes**.

The longer answer: Outbound (From Twilio to a phone number) can be done with the [Twilio REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) and we can send SMS to over 200 countries worldwide.

Inbound (From a cell phone to your web application via Twilio) can be done by purchasing a [Twilio phone number](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/incoming) and setting up the Request URL to make an HTTP POST request to your webserver like so:

[image]

This will have information about the inbound SMS message, which you can then reply to with some [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) or manipulate the information in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I want to Implement it for Australia but in pricing after selecting AUstralia I see that it is written in Local Phone number tab that Phone Number purchasing is not available here.- @phalt

Comment: Can you please let me know what is this Request Url and how can I work with this.

Comment: The Request URL is the URL that Twilio will send a webhook (a HTTP POST) request to when the phone number is called or send an sms message. Go to your numbers portal: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/incoming and click the phone number. The Request URL can be set up there.

Comment: For more complex questions Twilio has a great customer support service, which is free: http://twilio.com/help

Comment: I would use a third party platform that offers two-way services like https://pushsent.com